# Text and plot offset when called inside loop in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm observing a strange behavior when I try to output both text and a plot inside a loop in knitr.
When I run the below code, text and plot output are offset:

- the 1st text is not followed by any plot
- the 2nd text is followed by the 1st plot
- the 3rd text is followed by the 2ndt plot
- etc.
- the last text is followed by the second-last and the last plot

Is there any way to correct this, i.e. each text followed by its corresponding plot ?

````
```{r  echo=FALSE}


for (i in 1:5){

  cat("\nIteration number: ")

  cat(i)

  plot(1:i)

}

```
````

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: (FYI I just corrected a mistake in my question) I simply want an output with the text telling the iteration number followed by the corresponding plot. What happens currently is that the first text is not followed by any plot, the second text is followed by the first plot, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old bug in the `evaluate` package which has been fixed. See [issue #403](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/403) for details. The solutions is [FAQ 1](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md).

Comment: Thanks! I just updated to knitr 1.0.5 and evaluate 0.4.3, it works fine indeed.